# "peur de l'avenir" or "peur en l'avenir"

Tags: expressions, prépositions

> J'ai peur ___ l'avenir.

Usually with *peur* we would use *de*, but there are also several articles that use *en* in this expression, such as [here](http://www.estrepublicain.fr/edition-de-verdun/2016/12/19/travaux-publics-le-rebond-de-2016) and [here](http://www.medelu.org/La-gauche-a-l-epreuve-d-une). So is it correct to use *en*? If so, is there a difference between the two?

Comment: la première est une citation d'une personne interrogée oralement, ce n'est donc pas une référence. De plus ce cadre travaille dans l'industrie du bâtiment...Le deuxième est simplement une faute. Comparez les usages des deux expressions: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=peur+en+l%27avenir%2Cpeur+de+l%27avenir&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cpeur%20de%20l%27%20avenir%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpeur%20de%20l%27%20avenir%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPeur%20de%20l%27%20avenir%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use *de* here:

> *J'ai peur de l'avenir*

but

> *Je crois en l'avenir*

The verb and the complement are dictating which preposition to use.

> *J'ai peur en avion*

Comment: So do you believe that the writing in the links provided is incorrect?

Comment: Might be regionalisms or just plain mistakes.

Comment: Although "peur de l'avion" is also used, and understood as "afraid of taking a plane", not as "afraid of being eaten by a plane".

Comment: @Rightleg That depends, it would likely be the second case if you are a bird ;-)